# ConfigParser не отображает изменений в файле во время работы скрипта

Tags: python

Задача такова, если в файле `config.ini` и в глобальная переменной не одинаковы, выводить одно сообщение, если же одинаковы, другое.

python скрипт:

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
version = 10

def test():
    if config.getint('INFO', 'version') != version:
        print 'delete'
    else:
        print 'not delete'
    return 'done'
```

config.ini

```
[INFO]
version = 12
```

как бы я не менял `version =`  значение в `config.ini` всегда получаю `'delete'`

Comment: а как у вас это работает? у вас функция и переменная названы одним именем, из-за этого у меня валится скрипт. Если изменить имя функции, то все работает как надо. Может вы тестируете не тот же код, который привели в вопросе? В коде из вопроса у вас нет ошибок (ну только если значения не меняете в каком-то другом конфиге)

Comment: на счет имени функции я ступил ) её я измели. Но вот если я меняю в `config.ini` значение `version` на `10`, то он не выдает мне `not delete`, не перезапуская скрипт

Comment: а вы попробуйте `version = '10'`

Comment: а почему он должен выдать `not delete` без перезапуска скрипта? Как вы вызываете вашу функцию `test`? У вас постоянно что ли скрипт крутится или как?

Comment: @BOPOH да, скрипт крутится постоянно. Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы при изменение в файле во время работы скрипта, это и отображалось на нем.

Comment: тогда надо считывать данные (т.е. `config.read('config.ini')`) при каждом обращении к конфигу

Comment: @BOPOH больше спасибо, не подумал об этом

Comment: @BOPOH добавьте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @jfs, не уверен что это хорошее решение, не исключаю, что есть более правильный подход для этого, отвечают пусть те, кто в теме )) А я бы использовал что-то типа [вот этого](https://github.com/dtrillo/ConfigParserAdvanced/blob/master/ConfigParserAdvanced.py) и вызывал `reload` когда надо (например, когда мне [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) об этом скажет)

Comment: @BOPOH я имел в виду ответ типа: *"ConfigParser  не пытается читать с диска при getint() вызове, поэтому изменения не видны"* и в качестве решения можно просто переместить инициализацию внутрь `test()`. Использовать watchdog здесь является premature optimization (пока profiler не сказал что test() является узким местом в программе или же если не стоит явной задачи как можно быстрее заметить изменение).

Comment: @jfs, ну вот, у вас уже и ответ готов ) я на хорошие ответы ленивый, а на простые от меня и коммента хватит )